# Toshiba Satellite L755D Screen black

Tags: boot, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba Satellite L755D , laptop just "Black Screened". No Beep , No display on an external monitor either. I can hear the fan running and it trying to boot from DVD on startup.
I removed RAM and start up, it just give me long beep.

Comment: You don't even see the BIOS and POST messages at the beginning? The screen is _always_ black from the first moment when you turn the machine on?

Comment: Yes, No BIOS and POST message, nothing, just power on and fan is on. I did unplugged power cord and hold power switch for 1 min, nothing happen. But it gave me long beep when I removed RAM and turn ON it.